# MVC: Keeping sensitive data on client side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, session, cookies

I have been developing multi-tenancy MVC application.

When User logged in, my application decides which DB will be used for logged user by looking CompanyName data which is coming from another DB.

For decreasing DB traffic, I have been pulling CompanyName value from DB when user logged in, than I have been assigning this value to cookie. Its working well but;

My hesitation: If user could manupulate cookie value, can access to another company's DB.

What is the best practice of keeping sensitive data on client side? Encrypted cookie or something else?

Comment: Well, the approach will vary.  An encrypted cookie may suffice, since the server will store the encryption key.  So any manipulation would result in the client altering cipher text without any real foresight into what they've altered.  But without any real requirements or information the question is a bit broad.

Comment: Avoid to include sensitive data in cookies if you can. Anything on the user's computer can always be compromised.

However, if you need to, you should always encrypt. In that case, you should go for encryption through digital certificates. Encrypting it using AES would be good enough but remember to do it on server side

Comment: Show us how you are “assigning this value to cookie”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to not store any data on the client side. Store the data in the server session. This way, only a session id is stored on the client.

ASP.net automatically manages cookies to assign the server session to a client and also has some security checks built in to prevent clients from guessing valid session ids, session hijacking and session fixation. (Be sure to use the integrated mechanisms in ASP.net to do the user login)

Comment: The author is pretty broad in requirements, but you still have to do a bit of work to implement some of those security approaches.

Comment: I couldn't success to keeping data into sessions till end of the application. Sessions getting null when controller changed. Did you experienced ever this problem?

Comment: @HalitD A session timeout can be extended in the configuration, I believe the default is fifteen minutes.

Comment: @Greg I'm not mean timeout, its ending in a while. 10sec. Its ending when controller changed.

Comment: @Greg I think, I realized problem. I has been setting value to
HttpContext.Session["CompanyName"] out of controller, then I tried to read with same prefix in the controller.
I realized function changing when you run in controller, I changed to:
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CompanyName"]; than worked.